# How does the multiplication theorem correspond to the concept of intersection?

Tags: probability, soft-question, intuition

Given two events A and B defined on a sample space S.
S : Rolling a six-sided dice
A : Getting an even number
B : Getting a number ≥ 4

In an elementary sense (the experiment being carried out once), intersection refers to an outcome which satisfies both the events.
For our example,
A ∩ B = {4,6}
Hence P(A ∩ B) = 1/3

However, when we think about the multiplication theorem, we see that the experiment is carried on twice.
(We roll two six-sided dice, one after the other, and then calculate the probability of obtaining an even number on the first and a number ≥ 4 on the second)
P(A ∩ B) = P(A) × P(B)
P(A ∩ B) = 1/4

My problem lies in the fact that both of them are represented as A ∩ B.
(Which I think is a little bizarre give that in the first case, we carry out the experiment once, and in the second case, we carry it out twice)

To summarize my query - 
How does intersection, in the elementary sense, in which we perform the experiment once, correspond to the intersection we obtain from the multiplication theorem, in which we carry out the experiment twice?

Comment: The sets $A$,  $B$ are different in the two experiments. In the second, $A$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ in which the first element is any of $2,4,6$ and the second is any of $1,2,\dots,6$.

Comment: You are welcome. When the sample space is reasonably clear, such details are often omitted.

Comment: Do we have to think about concepts like conditional probability and Bayes' theorem differently for normal sets and sets with ordered pairs (in which experiments happen one after the another)?

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Although what you say is correct, it doesn't address the underlying error in the question, where the multiplication theorem was applied wrongly. Note that the sample space was explicitly stated as rolling **a** 6-sided die, and $A,B$ were defined as outcomes of that single die.

Comment: @user21820: I pointed out that the second experiment has a different sample space than the first, and that in particular the meanings of $A$ and $B$ are different in the two experiments, though the informal verbal descriptions are the same. Perhaps that helps.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yea it certainly is helpful, but the way the multiplication theorem was applied was wrong too, and probably the more serious mistake here. In probability theory we often add new random variables without bothering to prove any explicit isomorphism between the old and new spaces.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Oh I see; the asker was only concerned with the notation. If that's right then my answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The experiment, of rolling two dice one after the other, is carried out **once**. The sample space is the set of ordered pairs
$$S=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),\dots,(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)\}.$$

$$A=\{(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(6,1),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)\}.$$

$$B=\{(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,4),(5,5),(5,6),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)\}.$$

$$A\cap B=\{(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)\}.$$

Comment: Am I correct to deduce that we need to think about the concept of _conditional probability_ differently when the experiment is carried on _once_, as opposed to the experiment being carried on _twice_ (causing the sets to comprise of ordered pairs)?

Comment: For instance, when the experiment is carried on once, P(A|B)= P(A∩B)/P(B) ; where A,B are sets of _one tuple_. Whereas, when the experiment is carried on twice, the formula remains the same, but the sets A,B are _of two tuples_? Is this thought process correct?

Comment: @DhruvGupta: Yes, and when the same random process is done twice, and are independent of each other, P(A|B) is just P(A) and P(A∩B) is just P(A) P(B). In other words the formula is only useful when $A,B$ are not independent, which usually means we've only one random process and we have partial information about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir! I always used to think in terms of ordered pairs when experiments were carried twice, although I was never sure if i were right. Such reinforcement of thought made my day. I appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the two are not in general the same. You cited the multiplication theorem wrongly.$\def\pp{\mathbb{P}}$ It only applies for **independent** events $A,B$ that $\pp(A \cap B) = \pp(A) \pp(B)$.

In your example, $A,B$ are indeed not independent, and your calculations already show you that if $\pp(A \cap B) = \pp(A) \pp(B)$ then we would get $\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{4}$ which is a contradiction.

What happens when $A,B$ are independent is that in fact we can look at $A \cap B$ as either of the following:

1. the outcome being in both of $A,B$.
2. the same random process done twice, first outcome in $A$ and second outcome in $B$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are independent, in (1) knowing that the outcome is in $A$ gives no bias whatsoever to whether the outcome is in $B$ or not, and so it is no different from discarding the outcome, doing the random process again and testing whether the second outcome is in $B$. This is why (1) has the same probability as (2).